# after jQuery mobile pageShow silentscroll, page jumps to top

Tags: jquery-mobile

We have a basket page, where there are the products, and then the shipping methods. This is a `jQuery mobile` site.

What I want to achive, that if a shipping method selected, then if there is a page reload, jQuery mobile jumps to a `div` to the shipping methods.

Here is the code, what scrolls to the shipping methods. This is an inline script.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function (e, ui) {
    $.mobile.silentScroll($('#kosar').offset().top);
});
```

**Expected result**: on page refresh, the window scroll to the `#kosar` div.

**Current result**: page scrolls to the `#kosar` div, but immediatly scroll to the top of the page.

What we discovered, if some error is occures after the `silentScroll`, the window is not jump back to the top of the page. So it seems, something after the `pageshow` scrolls it to back, but we do not know, what.

For example:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function (e, ui) {
    $.mobile.silentScroll($('#kosar').offset().top);
    undefined_function(); //This function is not exists
});
```

Here are the non working, and "working" examples:

**[Here is a live example.](http://m.lay.hu/so.php)** When you refresh the page, you will see for a second the big red text, and immediatly after that you will be taken to the top of the page.

**[Here is the example with error.](http://m.lay.hu/so2.php)**

I've tested it in FF Developer Edition. With Chrome, you need to resize your browser to a littlebit smaller, and refresh some times to see the scrollbar how jumping to bottom and up.

How can I prevent this annoying scroll to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is a bug in the jQuery mobile js, I've reported it to them.

Finally I figured it out.

Version:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js

I've made a breakpoint in the jQuery mobile js `silentScroll` definition, and what I've see, for some reason it run twice. The first is a good call, `ypos` is a number, where I want to jump, this is why it jump to the right place.

But, later, at line 15432 here are these lines of codes, what is running on document ready:

```
// window load event
// hide iOS browser chrome on load if hideUrlBar is true this is as fall back incase we were too early before
if ( $.mobile.hideUrlBar ) {
    $window.load( $.mobile.silentScroll );
}
```

And when it's happens, on the second call, the `ypos` for `silentScroll` will be an object, not a number, as the function expects, and if it not a number, then jQuery mobile set the `ypos` to `$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll` what is actually 1 if you do not modified. This is why it jumps back to home.

Warning: If you think, you just need to set the `$.mobile.hideUrlBar` to false, you are wrong. I've tried it, but it had side effects, because in line 15416 there are another reference for this variable, and if you turn off, then when you go from a page to another, you wont be redirected to the top of your second page.

So the solution was to comment out this `$window.load( $.mobile.silentScroll );` and now everything is working as I expected.

Comment: Line 15432 is the non-min version. For the min version of 1.4.5 it's in the vicinity of line 9, column 6917. Removing '&&g.load(a.mobile.silentScroll)' after the 'a.mobile.hideUrlBar' worked for me. Thanks, @lolka-bolka this drove me mad for days!

Comment: @GeoffM A guy has fixed it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8200#issuecomment-221668762