# Text input undoes silentScroll and resets its position when the user is typing

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a Cordova mobile app. I have a local database (using brodybits' sqlite plugin for cordova) which contains the data I want to display in the app. The user can choose from 2 select lists and/or type in the search field.

**What I want is:** When the user presses inside the search box, the view of the app scrolls down so that the user gets to see the results immediately while typing his query.

The fiddle showing what I **want** it to do: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ppvvfws1/1

Code for the submit input:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" size="30" value="" class="text-input" placeholder="Search items" data-clear-btn="true" onclick="$.mobile.silentScroll(160)"/>
```

Code binding it to keyup:

```
var itemsearch = "";
$("#input").unbind();
$(function() {
            $("#input").keyup(function(e) {
                itemsearch = $("input#input").val(); 
                // queryDatabase uses the value of itemsearch to find items in the database that resemble its value
                queryDatabase();
            })
        });
```

**The problem:** Whenever the user types something inside the search box, or removes something from the search box, the page automatically jumps back up.

Unfortunately though, the problem I am having can't be seen on this fiddle as it only occurs when the call to the (local) database is made. When I comment it out (line 7 in index.js) the problem does not occur. Obviously though, leaving out the database call is not a solution for me as it contains all the data required for the app to work.

Code for database call:

```
function queryDatabase() {

            var outputListview = document.querySelector("#outputListview");
            var where = '';


            if (itemsearch && $("#itemsearch").prop('selectedIndex') != 0) {
                where += 'AND table.name LIKE ("%' + itemsearch + '%")';
            }


            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE table.name IS NOT NULL '+where, [], function (tx, results) {

                    var len = results.rows.length;

                    var createUnorderedListElem = document.createElement("ul");

                    if (len > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var createListItem = document.createElement("li");
                            createListItem.textContent = results.rows.item(i)['name'];
                            createUnorderedListElem.appendChild(createListItem);
                        }
                    }

                    outputListview.appendChild(createUnorderedListElem);
                });
            });
        }
```

I know it's messy, I'm new to this, but it works absolutely fine to retrieve the correct output. Except, of course, for the fact that when typing in the search field, the page jumps back to the top again (pre-silentScroll position) instead of staying still (post-silentScroll position).

I'm guessing it is a problem with the app *refreshing* the page whenever the user activates the keyboard, either to add characters to the query or delete characters from the query. But I have no idea what to do about it.

I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474402/after-jquery-mobile-pageshow-silentscroll-page-jumps-to-top) that seems to resemble my problem, although not exactly. And editing out the bit from the library file, which was suggested by a commenter, did not help me.

I hope my post was clear enough, and that anyone has any ideas as to what could be causing it and/or what I could try to solve it. Thanks in advance.

**edit:** For some reason, after I added a slider in my HTML the problem of jumping back to the top seems to have stopped. [Here is the editted JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppvvfws1/2/) which shows what element I mean. When I remove this element the problem starts occurring again. But I would still like to know what's causing this and how to prevent it, as I might re-arrange these elements later on.

I also tried replacing `onclick="$.mobile.silentScroll(160)"` with `onclick=" $.mobile.silentScroll($('#zoekmerknaam').offset().top)` but the problem remains the same.

Perhaps this new information might shed some light for someone?

Comment: Based on your description, I have made a simple website (http://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/37858492/) in order to replicate the problem, but without success. Could you post the `queryDatabase()` function code?

Comment: @GjermundDahl I've added in the code you requested, albeit anonymized. I hope it's of any use. And thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: It might be the `onclick` event. You could try to replace it with a standard jQuery binding, like `$("#input").focus(function(e) {$.mobile.silentScroll(160);}` Check the source code in the link I provided above.

Comment: @GjermundDahl Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it's giving me the exact same result :(

Comment: Busy day today, sorry for delayed comments. Could it be an error in the html code returned by the server? What happens if you replace queryDatabase() with e.g. outputListview.appendChild("<div>Some valid code</div>")